# Replace part of an image url

Tags: image, replace

I need to replace _MThumb with _Lthumb in the following dynamically generated html:

```
<img src="/images/images_MThumb.jpg" />
```

So it would render as:

```
<img src="/images/image_LThumb.jpg />
```

I've tried:

```
$('img').each(function () {

var src = $(this).attr('src');
$(this).attr('src', src.replace(/_MThumb(\.[^.]+)?$/, '_LThumb$1');
});
```

And:

```
$(".container img").attr("src", function(i, src) {
  return src.replace("_MThumb", "_LThumb");
```

And a few other variations.

Comment: Not a fix but the `<img>` tag does not use or need a closing slash.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dropping the semi colon at the end of the function worked (which surprised me):

```
$( window ).on( "load", function() {
$('img').each(function(){
var $this = $(this)
$this.attr('src',$this.attr('src').replace('_MThumb.jpg','_LThumb.jpg'))
})
});
```

Answer (score 0):

So long as you can count on the uri of the images staying consistent, you should be able to use a simple regex like:

```
$('img').each(function () {
    var src = $(this).attr('src');
    $(this).attr('src', src.replace(/_MThumb/, '_LThumb') ;
});
```